# Transformar string em operador

Tags: python-3.x, operadores

Tenho a seguinte string '1+1', tenho que transformar os números em inteiros e realizar a operação, tem como transformar a string '+' no operador +, ou outros operadores como o '*' fiz um primeiro esboço da operação usando if's, porém como são vários operadores queria fazer um código mais enxuto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fazer "certinho" é algo que depende de quanta funcionalidade você quer, e é algo que, se você quiser por exemplo, ler parênteses, pode ficar bem complicado.

Mas, para manter simples, vamos supor que as expressões de entrada sejam sempre da forma número, operador, numero e tudo separado por espaços - e também vamos deixar o próprio Python processar os operandos numéricos para dar o seu valor como um número flutuante. (isso é, vamos chamar o built-in "float" em vez de processar a entrada dígito por dígito para construir os operandos)

Daí focamos só no operador em si - e podemos criar um simples dicionário que mapeia o simbolo do operador para uma função que recebe dois parâmetros.  Para ficar mais curto ainda, podemos usar a palavra chave `lambda` que permite a definição de funções simples como expressões, dentro do próprio corpo do dicionário.

Daí dá para fazer algo desse tipo:

```
operadores = {
  "+": lambda op1, op2: op1 + op2,
  "-": lambda op1, op2: op1 - op2,
  "*": lambda op1, op2: op1 * op2,
  "/": lambda op1, op2: op1 / op2
}

def process(expression):
   op1, operator, op2 =expression.split()
   op1 = float(op1)
   op2 = float(op2)
   return operadores[operator](op1, op2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Estou assumindo que a sua string de entrada tem sempre o formato "**N**operador**N**" aonde **N** é o número presente na string. Caso seja **N**operador**M** a solução não irá funcionar.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html

```
import operator
def tamanho_do_numero(valor):
 tamanho = (len(valor)-1)//2 #tamanho de N. Importante para o slice
 return tamanho

valortotal = "111+111"
tamanhoN = tamanho_do_numero(valortotal)
calculo = { "+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub,"*": operator.mul,"/":operator.truediv}#etc
valorN=int((valortotal[:tamanhoN]))
operador = (valortotal[tamanhoN])

print (calculo[operador](valorN,valorN))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def calculate(num1, operation, num2): 
    if operation == "+":
      out =  num1 + num2
    elif operation == "-":
      out = num1 - num2
    elif operation == "*":
      out = num1 * num2
    elif operation == "/":
      out = (num1 / num2) if num2 != 0 else print ('null')
    else: 
      out = print ('null')
    return out
```